# Match an array of possible tokens and return the matched token and its position

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I'm writing a sound change program in Java which should replace patterns of tokens with a replacement string only if they match the pattern string.

The pattern string can contain literal strings and/or variables using `%TokenName`. Such a variable references a `Token` class containing a `List` of `String`s containing the possible token values. An optional anchor to specifiy the location of the pattern (`^` and `$` like in regex ) can preceed or succeed the pattern. All whitespace is deleted while processing the replace.

The following example should only match when first a `ShortVowel` token occurs, followed by a `VoicelessStop`, and the the string should end:

```
%ShortVowel %VoicelessStop $
```

with the folloing tokens:

```
ShortVowel: ɑ ɛ ɪ jɪ ɔ ə
VoicelessStop: k p t
```

I want the replacer to return an array of a `ReplacerMatch` class containing the `List` of `String`s with the matched tokens per variable, and the start and end positions of the total match in the string to be processed. For every match in the string, such a class exists in the array.

This means the string `dɛt` should return

```
[
  matches: [ɛ, t]
  startPosition: 1
  endPosition: 3
]
```

and the string `drɛkɔp` should return

```
[
  matches: [ɔ, p]
  startPosition: 4
  endPosition: 6
]
```

since only matches at the end of the string are matched. The string `dɛ` should return an empty array.

---

The `ReplacerMatch` class is defined as follows:

```
public class ReplacerMatch
{
  private List<String> matches;
  private int startPosition;
  private int endPosition;

  [...]
}
```

Such a replace rule is defined in a `Replacer` class:

```
public class Replacer
{
  enum Anchor
  {
    NONE,
    STRING_START,
    STRING_END;

    public static Anchor fromString(String string)
    {
      if (string.startsWith("^"))
        return STRING_START;
      else if (string.endsWith("$"))
        return STRING_END;
      else
        return NONE;
    }
  }

  private String pattern;
  private String replacement;
  private List<Token> tokens;

  [...]
}
```

The `Token` class contains the name of that token and a list of `String` with possible token values. These values can be of variable length.

```
public class Token
{
  private final String name;
  private final List<String> tokens;

  [...]
}
```

---

So far I've written the code in the `Replacer` class to split the pattern string into a list of `Token`s and extract the `Anchor`.

```
public ReplacerMatch[] matches(String string)
{
  String pat = this.pattern;

  // Get anchor
  Anchor anchor = Anchor.fromString(pat);
  if (anchor == Anchor.STRING_START)
    pat = pat.substring(1);
  else if (anchor == Anchor.STRING_END)
    pat = pat.substring(0,pat.length() - 1);

  // Parse variables
  List<Token> vars = new ArrayList<>();
  Pattern varPattern = Pattern.compile("%(\\w+)");
  Matcher varMatcher = varPattern.matcher(pat);
  while (varMatcher.find())
  {
    for (Token t : this.tokens)
    {
      if (t.getName().equals(varMatcher.group(1)))
      {
        vars.add(t);
        pat = pat.replace(varMatcher.group(),"%");
        varMatcher.reset(pat);
        break;
      }
    }
    // Error handling on non-existing token
  }

  return new ReplacerMatch[0];
}
```

Now I'm stuck on the matching of the variables, which seems to be quite hard or impossible with regex. Does anybody have an idea how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your Token class, you can convert its tokens field into a Java Pattern object by

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[").append(tokens.get(0));
for (int i = 1; i < tokens.size(); i++){
    sb.append('|').append(tokens.get(i));
}
sb.append(']');
return sb.toString();
```

If you replace in the user supplied pattern every instance of a Token name with the Token pattern like

```
String javaPattern = userPattern.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
for (Token t : tokens){
    javaPattern = javaPattern.replaceAll('%'+t.getName(), t.toPatternString());
}
return Pattern.compile(javaPattern);
```

then you get a Pattern that matches as your user expects, and you just have to extract the matched parts.

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userInput);
if (matcher.matches()){
    // this gives you the limits
    matcher.start();
    matcher.end();

    // this is the matched bit
    String matchedString = matcher.group();
    // now you've got to follow your %some %some $ pattern to separate the parts of the matchedString. You have to parse your pattern into parts and for each of those part find the part in matchedString that matches
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not thought in that way at all. With a fex tweaks the code works!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the completeness, here are the finished `matches()` and `replace()` methods of the `Replacer` class:

```
public List<ReplacerMatch> matches(String string)
{
  String regex = this.pattern;
  List<ReplacerMatch> matches = new ArrayList<>();

  for (Token t : this.tokens)
    regex = regex.replaceAll('%' + t.getName(),t.toPattern());

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
  while (m.find())
  {
    string = string.substring(0,m.start()) + Util.filledString('%',m.group().length()) + string.substring(m.end());

    List<String> local = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i ++)
      local.add(m.group(i + 1));

    matches.add(new ReplacerMatch(local,m.start(),m.end()));
  }

  return matches;
}

public String replace(String string)
{
  List<ReplacerMatch> matches = this.matches(string);
  if (matches.isEmpty())
    return string;

  int increase = 0;
  for (ReplacerMatch m : matches)
  {
    String replaced = this.replacement;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.getMatches().size(); i ++)
    {
      String match = m.getMatches().get(i);
      String pattern = "%" + (i + 1);
      replaced = replaced.replace(pattern,match);
    }

    string = string.substring(0,m.getStartPosition() + increase) + replaced + string.substring(m.getEndPosition() + increase);
    increase += (replaced.length() - m.getMatchesAsString().length());
  }
  return string;
}
```